# Column 'available_for_order' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm strugling with this query within prestashop , i know it could be easily fixed by changing to `sa.available_for_order` but this way it breaks the logic of other core files ,
is there any other way around to fix this without renaming `available_for_order` to `sa.available_for_order` ,

```
SELECT
  a.`id_product`,
  b.`name` AS `name`,
  `reference`,
  a.`price` AS `price`,
  sa.`active` AS `active`,
  `newfield`,
  shop.`name` AS `shopname`,
  a.`id_shop_default`,
  image_shop.`id_image` AS `id_image`,
  cl.`name` AS `name_category`,
  sa.`price`,
  0 AS `price_final`,
  a.`is_virtual`,
  pd.`nb_downloadable`,
  sav.`quantity` AS `sav_quantity`,
  sa.`active`,
  IF(sav.`quantity` <= 0, 1, 0) AS `badge_danger`,
  sa.`available_for_order` AS `available_for_order`
FROM
  `ps_product` a
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_product_lang` b
ON
  (
    b.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND b.`id_lang` = 1 AND b.`id_shop` = 1
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_stock_available` sav
ON
  (
    sav.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND sav.`id_product_attribute` = 0 AND sav.id_shop = 1 AND sav.id_shop_group = 0
  )
JOIN
  `ps_product_shop` sa
ON
  (
    a.`id_product` = sa.`id_product` AND sa.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_category_lang` cl
ON
  (
    sa.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` AND b.`id_lang` = cl.`id_lang` AND cl.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_shop` shop
ON
  (
    shop.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_image_shop` image_shop
ON
  (
    image_shop.`id_product` = a.`id_product` AND image_shop.`cover` = 1 AND image_shop.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_image` i
ON
  (
    i.`id_image` = image_shop.`id_image`
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `ps_product_download` pd
ON
  (pd.`id_product` = a.`id_product`)
WHERE
  1 AND `available_for_order` = 1
ORDER BY
  a.`id_product` ASC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

PRESTASHOP

```
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
    $this->_select .= ',sa.`available_for_order` AS `available_for_order`, ';
             $this->fields_list['sa!available_for_order'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Available for order'),
                'width' => 90,
                'active' => 'available_for_order',
                'filter_key' => 'sa!available_for_order',
                'type' => 'bool',
                'align' => 'center',
                'orderby' => false
            );
}
```

Comment: Is the query generated through `renderList()` in admin controller?

Comment: yes i ovveride the adminController

i updated the main method thread with the overide , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your fields list to use having filter.

```
$this->fields_list['available_for_order'] = array(
            'title' => $this->l('Available for order'),
            'width' => 90,
            'active' => 'available_for_order',
            'filter_key' => 'available_for_order',
            'havingFilter' => true,
            'type' => 'bool',
            'align' => 'center',
            'orderby' => false
        );
```

This will use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` in query.

`WHERE` clause does not work on column aliases but `HAVING` does.

Answer (score 0):

The column `available_for_order` must be in more than one of the tables.  Just qualify the column name, as you do in the `select`:

```
WHERE 1 AND sa.available_for_order = 1
------------^
```

Comment: sorry ,but i need it to be `available_for_order` not `sa.available_for_order`
as specified in the title ,if i put it a sa.  it removes the toggle and shows the values as 0 / 1
anyway , thank you for your answer